# takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) celery simple process

Tags: flask, celery

Trying to run a simple command in a celery task but getting 'takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)' every time I try to execute.

I am able to perform the 'add' celery task without issue and I see in the celery log that it tells me the result (i'm on debug)...   but when I try to run the bash_run task it has a exception

```
[2014-09-24 22:17:08,240: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x10dba12a8> (args:('tasks.bash_run', 'c75860c4-71b2-4ce6-881d-3ed208038891', ('/bin/sleep 50',), {}, {'utc': True, u'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, u'group': None, 'args': ('/bin/sleep 50',), 'retries': 0, u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, u'hostname': 'celery@MKT2AHF1G3', 'task': 'tasks.bash_run', 'callbacks': None, u'correlation_id': u'c75860c4-71b2-4ce6-881d-3ed208038891', 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, u'reply_to': u'98d88cb9-6883-3f1d-a1ef-422df9175c88', 'id': 'c75860c4-71b2-4ce6-881d-3ed208038891', u'headers': {}}) kwargs:{})
[2014-09-24 22:17:08,243: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: tasks.bash_run[c75860c4-71b2-4ce6-881d-3ed208038891] pid:21290
[2014-09-24 22:17:08,246: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.bash_run[c75860c4-71b2-4ce6-881d-3ed208038891] raised unexpected: TypeError('bash_run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andy.terhune/coregrapherenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andy.terhune/coregrapherenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: bash_run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**My code:**

```
SECRET_KEY = 'not_a_secret'
CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {'tasks.bash_run': {'rate_limit': '2/s'}}

from celery import Celery
import settings
import flask
import os

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(name="tasks.bash_run")
def bash_run(command):
    f = os.popen(command)
    output = f.read()
    return output

@celery.task(name="tasks.add")
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_stuff():
    #working...
    #res=add.delay(23,43)
    #print res.task_id
    #print res.get()

    #not working...
    string = '/bin/sleep 50'
    res = bash_run.delay(string)
    print res.task_id
```

Comment: Remove `CELERY_ANNOTATIONS` & try running it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try putting the bash_run task in its own module. I experienced the same error. Guessing that Celery gets confused when multiple different method signatures occur in the same module, I moved my failing task into its own module. The problem went away for me.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working but have no idea why this hacky solution is necessary, maybe a bug?

```
@celery.task(name="tasks.bash_run")
def bash_run(dummy, command):
    f = os.popen(command)
    output = f.read()
    return output


def get_stuff():
    #working...
    #res=add.delay(23,43)
    #print res.task_id
    #print res.get()

    #not working...
    string = '/bin/sleep 50'
    res = bash_run.delay('', string)
    print res.task_id
```

Answer (score -2):

It's weird, I run into the same problem just now, trying to run this task:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_signup_email(user_id):
    # fetch user
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    # send verification email
    send_verification_email(user)
```

turns out since it was in a `tasks.py` file and celery was configured to auto discover tasks in Django apps' `tasks.py` files, the `bind=True` was redundant. everything returned to normal as soon as I removed the `bind=True` argument, meaning it didn't require two arguments anymore :-\